# How to sort by 'value' of a specific key within a property stored as an array with k-v pairs in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongodb collection, let's call it `rows` containing documents with the following general structure:

```
{
  "setid" : 154421,
  "date" : ISODate("2014-02-22T14:06:48.229Z"),
  "version" : 2,
  "data" : [
    {
      "k" : "name",
      "v" : "ryan"
    },
    {
      "k" : "points",
      "v" : "375"
    },
    {
      "k" : "email",
      "v" : "ryan@123.com"
    }
  ],
}
```

There is no guarantee what values of `k` and `v` might populate the "data" property for any particular document (eg. other documents might have 5 k-v pairs with different key names in it). The only rule is that documents with the same `setid` have the same k-v pairs. (i.e. the `rows` collection might hold 100 other documents with `setid = 154421`, that have the same set of 3 keys in the data property: `"name"`, `"points"`, `"email"`, with their own respective values.

How would one, with this setup, construct a query to retrieve all rows with a particular `setid` sorted by `points`? I need, in effect, some way of saying 'sort by the the field `data.v` where the value of `k==points` or something like that...?

Something like this:

```
db.rows.find({setid:154421},{$sort:{'data.v',-1}, {$where: k:'points'}}})
```

I know this is the incorrect syntax, but I'm just taking a stab at it to illustrate my point.

Is it possible?

Comment: So for **one** value of `setid` you have a number of documents that you want to sort by the `v` value from the element containing `k` equal to "points". Is this what you are asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that what you want would be all the documents that have the "points" value as a "key" in the array, and then sort on the "value" for that "key", then this is a little out of scope for the `.find()` method.

Reason being if you did something like this

```js
db.collection.find({
    "setid": 154421, "data.k": "point" }
).sort({ "data.v" : -1 })
```

The problem is that *even though* the matched elements **do** have the matching key of "point", there is no way of telling **which** `data.v` you are referring to for the sort. Also, a `sort` within `.find()` results will not do something like this:

```
db.collection.find({
    "setid": 154421, "data.k": "point" }
).sort({ "data.$.v" : -1 })
```

Which would be *trying* to use a positional operator within a sort, essentially telling which element to use the value of `v` on. But this is not supported and not likely to be, and for the most likely explaination, that "index" value would be likely different in every document.

But this kind of *selective* sorting can be done with the use of [**`.aggregate()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/).

```js
db.collection.aggregate([

    // Actually shouldn't need the setid
    { "$match": { "data": {"$elemMatch": { "k": "points" } } } },

    // Saving the original document before you filter
    { "$project": {
        "doc": {
           "_id": "$_id",
           "setid": "$setid",
           "date": "$date",
           "version": "$version",
           "data": "$data"
        },
        "data": "$data"
    }}

    // Unwind the array
    { "$unwind": "$data" },

    // Match the "points" entries, so filtering to only these
    { "$match": { "data.k": "points" } },

    // Sort on the value, presuming you want the highest
    { "$sort": { "data.v": -1 } },

    // Restore the document
    { "$project": {
        "setid": "$doc.setid",
        "date": "$doc.date",
        "version": "$doc.version",
        "data": "$doc.data"
    }} 

])
```

Of course that presumes the `data` array only has the **one** element that has the key points. If there were more than one, you would need to `$group` before the sort like this:

```js
    // Group to remove the duplicates and get highest
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$doc",
        "value": { "$max": "$data.v" }
    }},

    // Sort on the value
    { "$sort": { "value": -1 } },

    // Restore the document
    { "$project": { 
        "_id": "$_id._id",
        "setid": "$_id.setid",
        "date": "$_id.date",
        "version": "$_id.version",
        "data": "$_id.data"
    }}
```

So there is one usage of [**`.aggregate()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) in order to do some **complex** sorting on documents and still return the original document result in full.

Do some more reading on [aggregation operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) and the general framework. It's a useful tool to learn that takes you beyond `.find()`.

Comment: yes this works. thanks! Now the issue is that the points are being interpreted as strings, and therefore sorting as such (rather than numerically, alhabetically, i.e. 9, 87, 82, 7, 653. What I want is: 653, 87, 82, 9, 7. Is there a quick fix for that? Something akin to parseInt() during the $project?

Comment: @trip41 You data isn't being "interpreted", that is how things are clearly recorded. Only you can fix your data. If you require numeric information then update it to be numeric. But no you cannot "cast" types in mongodb like this. Fix the values and the sorting will work.

Comment: Unfortunately the data is being populated arbitrarily by users, from arbitrary data-sources and I have no way of predicting what will be a string or a number at the time of document creation. I could of course perform some regex matching and determine if values for certain keys contain only numbers that it's likely the intention is numeric, but that seems presumptuous (and risky). What if, say, one of the documents contained a points value with non-numeric characters as well -- it would either be ignored or throw an error