# Clarification on sorting subsets in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have documents with fields `a, b, c, d, e, p` in mongodb.
I have indexes for `{ a: 1 }`, `{ b: 1 },`{ c: 1 }, `{ d: 1 },`{ e: 1 }, `{ p: 1 }`, AS WELL as compound indexes `{ a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 }`.
The field `p` represents the position of the fields.

If I have a select like this: `{ a: 'something', b: 'something else', c: 'and again' }`, I know it will definitely use the index `{ a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 }` to search (obviously).

However, if I then want to sort by `p` ( `{ p: 1 }`), will indexes actually be used to sort the data? I am worried  because I can potentially have a large dataset.

I read http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/ and cannot *quite* figure out my use case (although it's probably there)

Comment: I would expect it to use the index, but you should be able to verify it by using `explain()`: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/

Comment: I gather you are being very general about your actual data, but since you mention "postions" would this be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22289793/2313887

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably best said as *"Can MongoDB use one index to match and another one to sort?"* And the answer to that is no.

The thing to be "looking" for in the explain output to see if an index was used to sort is the value for [scanAndOrder](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#explain.scanAndOrder) which will show `true` when an index **cannot** be used and `false` where it can.

Considering you adapted sample, with a compound index on "a", "b", and "c" and a separate index on "p", then a query like this:

```js
db.collection.find( { a: "a", b: "b" }).sort({ p: 1 }).explain()
```

Would show you that the compound index was used for the query, but was not used for the sort. But if you had an index created like this:

db.collection.ensureIndex({ a: 1, b: 1, p: 1 })

Then the index **would** be used for the sort. In a similar fashion, if you has created like this:

db.collection.ensureIndex({ p: 1, a: 1, b: 1 })

Then that index could also be selected and would be done so by the sort action and also used as the sort. But would not be very efficient as all of the values for `a` and `b` would be scanned in the index to determine the result.

As I final case with a very small anount of documents and your original compound selections it is likely that the optimizer would just pick the "p" index, given the small amount of documents to scan an the fact that it could then just use that index to affect the sort operation.

Comment: So, the best way to go is to actually do `db.collection.ensureIndex({ a: 1, b: 1, p: 1 })` to make sure that m query is indexed... right?

Comment: @Merc If your requirement to actually match meets something like that then yes. Try not to create too many indexes, or too many compound fields, and keep a limit to the fields that you commonly use.